# Run "Shoes::Every" in background of a Shoes::App (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, shoes

I have been working on a makeshift RPG, and the Regenerate function, is supposed to be called every 3 seconds, **NO MATTER WHAT THE PLAYER's STATUS IS**
For Example:

```
Shoes.app do
  # Display on main screen

  animate do
    # Set para(s) to current values of health and other stats
  end

  every 3 do
    RegenerateVitals
  end

end
```

But at times, the user will click on buttons that will trigger functions and new windows (the base window will keep opened in the background at all times.)
Do the every function really runs behind the scenes every 3 seconds no matter what menu the player is on? Or do I need to do something else for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the specification is that `every` calls the block no matter what (as long as the main windows stays open). I looked up the implementation of [shoes4](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4) and that one definitely does it (using the SWT scheduler) but other implementations such as Shoes 3.1, 3.2 and green shoes should do the same.